# To_char function in databricks

Tags: databricks

I am using sql as language for my notebook in databricks.
Want to get the day of week from the date given.
For doing this i used to_char(date,'fmday').  Getting error as function is not registered as temporary or permanant in databricks. Is there a way to get the name of day by other means.
Date is in format yyyymmdd

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because `to_char` is not a SparkSQL function. You can see the list of functions in the ScalaDocs here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html

If your date is a DateType, you can do `dayofweek(date)` in SparkSQL.

Answer (score 1):

> get the name of the day

Being as you want to get the name of the day, you can use the `date_format` function with the argument `'EEEE'` to get the day name, eg Monday.  If you want to pass in an integer (eg numbers between 1 and 7) then you could just code a `CASE` statement, something like:

```
%sql
SELECT 
  dayofweek( CAST( '2018-12-31' AS DATE ) ) AS  d,
  date_format( CAST( '2018-12-31' AS DATE ), 'EEEE' ) AS dayname, 
  CASE dayofweek( CAST( '2018-12-31' AS DATE ) ) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday' 
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday' 
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday' 
    ELSE 'Unknown' 
  END AS caseTest
```

NB I have coded the `CASE` to start the week from **Day 1 - Monday**, which is different to the `dayofweek` default; this might be one reason to do that, ie you want a different default.

My Results:

[image: My results]

Answer (score 0):

I got a way to get the name of day of week as below

date_format(to_date('20170821','yyyyMMdd'),'EEEE')

Now i want to pass a column of integer datatype, but when i pass it to query getting null as output. Could someone please help