# Timestamp to date | Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, mssql-jdbc

I want to select a column which is from datatype "datetime" in Orcale DB in date format.

```
column
1/31/2006 22:00:00 AM
```

I tried the following queries and got errors like below

```
select DATE_FORMAT(column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as column from table
ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier

select TO_DATE(column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as column from table
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

select TO_DATE(column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from table
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: to_date(column,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh 2006-31-01

Comment: `Cast(column as DATE)`  if you want a DATE type for futher date ariphmetic expressions.

Comment: Oracle does not have a data type "datetime".  It has `date` and `timestamp`.   My guess is that you mean that the column is of type `date`.  What data type do you want returned?  A string "2006-31-01"?  A `date` with the time component set to midnight?  Something else?

Comment: You've also tagged this `mssql-jdbc` which is the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver.  But that driver only works to connect to a SQL Server database.  It doesn't make sense in combination with the `oracle` tag.  If you are using the Oracle database, you aren't using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver to connect.  And vice versa.  If you are connecting to a SQL Server database, there is a `datetime` data type but the answers will be completely different because SQL Server doesn't have `to_char` or `to_date` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) to convert a date to a specific string format.

```
select to_char(dat_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as column from table;
```

If you are expecting a `date` as return type, then that is more about the client you are using. You could set a session level parameter like this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Comment: Setting the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` will not change anything in 3rd-party applications such as C#, Java, PHP, Python, etc. It is used internally within the Oracle database (for implicit casts between strings and dates) and in a few client applications such as SQL/Plus and SQL Developer (which are both Oracle products) as a **display** format but it does not change that the data type still has year-to-second components.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, there is no "datetime" data type. There is either `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and they both have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components (`TIMESTAMP` also has optional fractional seconds and time zone components). Both of those data types are binary data types and do **NOT** store a format.

If you want to set the time component of a `DATE` to midnight then use:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(date_column) AS date_column_at_midnight
FROM   table_name;
```

If you want to **display** a `DATE` column with only year, month and day components then you need to convert to a data type that does support a formatting; i.e. a string.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS formatted_date_string
FROM   table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a column of datatype `TIMESTAMP` to datatype `DATE` use the `CAST` function ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75)) :

```
select CAST(column AS DATE) as dt_column from table
```

The error "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" indicates that the SQL engine is unable to determine what table the column belongs to. To avoid that make sure to alias all joined tables and use the alias for those columns. Like this:

```
select CAST(t1.column AS DATE) as dt_column from table t1
```

Comment: Does it not transforms the column to varchar?

Comment: @MirelKhok Yes. However, a `DATE` **always** has year-to-second components and is a binary data type that does **not** store any format so if you want to display it in a different format then you need to convert to a different data type (i.e. a string).

Comment: @MireKhok I changed my answer - now I'm showing how to convert timestamp to date. In your question you say "date format" that implies a format but I think you meant "date datatype". Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Using `CAST` will not remove the time component as, in Oracle, a `DATE` **always** has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. The client application may chose not to display them but they are always there. If you want to **display** the date (or timestamp) without a time component then you need to convert it to a data type that does support formatting such as a string.

Comment: I tried "to_char" and I got org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'to_char'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.

Comment: Ahh... all answers you are getting are for oracle sql. The error indicates you are using apache spark sql - that seems to use its own syntax (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251201/to-char-function-in-databricks). Can't help you with that maybe others can. Please tag your question correctly.